# Embed API demo not working

Tags: google-analytics-api

I tried using this Google Analytics Embed API Demo, of course with my own ClientID (49803909):

[Embed API Demo](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/)

However, instead of the graphic I should be getting, I only get a blank page. I did follow the instructions quite carefully. Does this work for others? Any ideas of what may be wrong?

PS: Here's the screenshot of where I am getting the id from. @DaImTo was right that just 49803909 wasn't it, but I also tried to full long string and even the service id below (the one with @), all to the same effect (a blank screen). So, is this the wrong screen then?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: 49803909 <-- is not a client id. should I assume you changed it or is that your View id from Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

I think @DalmTo is correct. You're most likely using one of [the many other Google Analytics IDs](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/account-explorer/) instead of using a valid Client ID (which is not Google Analytics-specific, it's a general ID used for accessing Google APIs), and you're probably getting errors logged to the JavaScript console that say something to that affect.

If you follow the steps in this [Embed API Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide), you'll see instructions on how to create a Client ID to use with the Embed API.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the question with a screenshot of where I obtained the id from. Can you please let me know if that is the wrong place to get it?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages logged to the JavaScript console?

Comment: The client ID is that whole string, starting with `4232...` and ending with `...apps.googleusercontent.com`.

Comment: Hi Philip, thanks. I see you are the creator of the app. The problem is that I don't know how to authorize my internal server (no public URL) as an authorized origin. I tried http://localhost:8080 like the instructions suggest but it is not working.

Comment: You just put in the origin of the server your page is running on. For example, if your page is at `http://www.example.com/embed-api/test.html` you'd set `http://www.example.com/` as the allowed origin.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I understood that. I should have stressed that this is an internal server. There is no public domain name for it. Does that mean the app cannot be used in this case?

Comment: No, that shouldn't affect anything. But instead of asking me, just try it. Worst case scenario, it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Well, like I said, I had tried "localhost" before asking you, and it didn't work. Since there is no url for this server, I couldn't try anything else. Asking you (or anyone else here) is still worthwhile because there may be a setting for this particular case that I don't know about (after all, it would be surprising if the tool only worked for servers with public domain names).